# Invalid use of Property

Tags: vba, excel

**TESTING MODULE**

```
Private Sub fooTest()

   Dim foo As cSegment
   Set foo = New cSegment

   foo.ParseSegment

   Debug.Print foo.Segment

End Sub
```

**CLASS**

```
Option Explicit

Private pElements As Collection
Private pSegmentData As String

Public Property Let ParseSegment(value As String)
   pSegmentData = value
   ParseElements pSegmentData
End Property
```

I keep getting an error on `foo.ParseSegment` saying "Invalid Use of property"

I'm not sure whats wrong here, as to my understanding my `Let` property is setup correctly. Does anyone know why I might be getting this error message?

Comment: Its a property let so expects to be assigned a value: `foo.ParseSegment = something` where `something` is set to `value` within the routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a property, not a method(Sub).  You are trying to call it like a method.  Property assignments must be assigned to.

```
foo.ParseSegment = ""
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, got my `Let` and `Get` mixed up, ... fixed now.

Comment: Perfect it works great now! Appreciate the hasty response :)